# como sumir janela de CMD apos utilizar os.system no python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

Tenho um código em Python 2.7 que abre um PDF com `os.system('meuarquivo.pdf')` e ele abre direitinho. Porém ao abrir o arquivo ele também abre uma janela de CMD vazia. Tem algum jeito de eu fechar essa janela ou evitar que ela apareça?

```
os.system('MeuArquivo.pdf')
```

Meu código fica completamente inutilizado enquanto eu não fecho esse arquivo. Gostaria que ele abrisse como um arquivo comum e que não necessariamente ficasse atrelado ao código.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri como fazer.

Posso substituir `os.system()` por:

```
subprocess.Popen([File],shell=True)
```

Assim ele não trava o código e não abre a janela do CMD.